# I can't make .navigate() work when I define sections in my page object

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Using [Nightwatch](http://nightwatchjs.org/) I've created a page object that looks much like this

```
module.exports = {

    url() {
        return `${this.api.launchUrl}/mypage`;
    },

    sections: {

        main: {

            selector: '.foo',

            elements: {
                bar: '[name="baz"]',
            },
        },
    },
};
```

And in my test's `before()` function I invoke it like this

```
module.exports = {

    before(browser) {
        const page = browser.page.buy.myPageObject();
        page.navigate();
        page.sections.main.waitForElementVisible('@bar');
    },

    (...)
};
```

And I'm greeted with total silence. No errors are logged, no browser window opens and after a while the process just exits silently.

Now if I change my page object to not using sections:

```
module.exports = {

    url() {
        return `${this.api.launchUrl}/mypage`;
    },

    //sections: {

    //    main: {

    //        selector: '.foo',

            elements: {
                bar: '[name="baz"]',
            },
    //    },
    //},
};
```

and change the appropriate line in the test to `page.waitForElementVisible('@bar');` my test runs fine.

I can't find any mention of me not being able to use `url()` in addition to `sections` in the [docs](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#defining-sections) so my question is: am I missing something obvious here? Is this something I'm not meant to be doing?

I would at least expect some kind of error message if I'm doing something wrong. There's no syntax errors in the surrounding code, it's succesfully parsed by eslint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further digging reveals that the actual issue is not being able to use commands on sections.

There is an open issue for this flagged as enchancement on [github](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/634).

Long story short, the workaround is

```
    const selector = page.section.main.selector;
    page.waitForElementVisible(selector);
```

Now this is not "feature-equivalent" since it just waits for the section to be there, but that's fine and the tests can check that the input actually exists. The main point of the wait in the before is to wait for the page to render anyway.